# Get date from datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Hi this is my datepicker

HTML:

```
 <div class="field-birthday field-return" id="birthday-edit" style="display:none;">
   <div class="birthdaypicker"></div>
   <input class="hidden" name="birthday" type="hidden" id="birthday" >
```

And this is in the .js:

```
$('.birthdaypicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd MM'
}).on("change", function(){
    var date = $('input[name="birthday"]').val($(this).val());
    console.log(date);
}).datepicker('setDate', "-30y");
```

I'm new in jQuery, js,.. and I'm quite lost, I need to get the value of the chosen date but I could not find any clear exemple about who to do it! Help is needed! Thanks!

Comment: I believe `birthdaypicker` needs to be a class on your input element, not the containing `<div>`

Comment: Use `datapicker`'s `altField` option to fill in the hidden field automatically.

Comment: Why don't you try something that's already there? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Comment: Here is [**JQuery UI Datepicker API Documentation**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
$('.birthdaypicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd MM'
}).on("change", function(){
   $('input[name="birthday"]').val($(this).val()); // remove  var date and set date here
    console.log($('input[name="birthday"]').val()); // directly get date here
}).datepicker('setDate', "-30y");
```

Comment: Neat job with the changes explained as comments beside each line.